# MVC 4 Entity Framework Optional Foreign Key On User Profile

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my User model I need an optional constraint to an active playlist.

```
public class User
{
    //.. Properties

    public int? ActivePlaylistID { get; set; }
    public virtual Playlist ActivePlaylist { get; set; }
}
```

In my database i have ActivePlaylistID set to nullable with a relationship established as: 'ActivePlaylistID' is a foreign key on table 'Playlists', column 'ID'.

In my Playlist model i have:

```
public class Playlist : BaseModel
{
    //.. Properties

    public int CreatedByUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

The CreatedByUserID relationship is established in my database and the model property is set in my controller before saving a new Playlist.

I get the following error at this point in the setup:

```
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'SyncFinder.Models.Playlist' and 'SyncFinder.Models.User'. 
The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
```

So in my DbEntity i added the following to my model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.ActivePlaylist)
    .WithRequired(x => x.CreatedByUser);
```

At this point the view loads, but when trying to add a new playlist to my database i get:

```
A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'ID'.
```

I am not sure how to resolve this constraint issue and the stacktrace isn't providing much detail except that the operation fails when trying to save the playlists repository.

Comment: EF doesn't like 1-1 relations. It wants a 1-many.

Comment: Seems like something it should be able to handle.  I imagine it is a requirement in a good amount of projects, if not all.

Comment: You could try `modelBuilder.Entity<Playlist>().HasKey(e => e.CreatedByUserID);` in addition to what you have shown. I am not sure EF plays well with 1-1 though.

Comment: Wow i think that did it!  I need to do some extensive testing, but at the moment it seems likely it is fixed.  Thanks a bunch, you are a wizard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one half of the relation was bound in the model binder. I am uncertain of the full support for one-to-one relations in Entity Framework, but for your example completing the relation should work

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Playlist>().HasKey(e => e.CreatedByUserID);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
 .HasOptional(x => x.ActivePlaylist)
 .WithRequired(x => x.CreatedByUser);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is related or not, but my junction table does not work for the other constraint i have on these 2 tables (a many to many relationship).  No data will load, and when i try to add either a user to a playlist or a playlist to a user i get an error:  The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_junc_UserPlaylists_Playlists". The conflict occurred in database "SyncFinder", table "dbo.Playlists", column 'ID'.  Could the above be introducing this error?  The data is fine in the controller before save is called.

Comment: When i add a new playlist to the db, after the save the playlist id is not the correct id.  In this case, the ActivePlaylistID on user is 8, but the newly added playlist should be 11, but inspecting the values shows it is 8 after the save.  I think EF is getting very confused by all these constraints.

Comment: I ended up scrapping this whole portion.  EF really does not like it, after removing all this code my junction table is binding again.  I guess i have to create a new junction table just for this 1 property.  seems like a waste, but its better than the headache this has already been.  Thanks again.